# Titanium Text field border style to none for Android

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I need to remove the border for my text field.
Default border style for Titanium Text field  is `Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_NONE` . But It is default only to iPhone. 
I have also turned the `borderColor = 'white'` ,which was my backgroundColor. But doesn't work.
Any solutions ?

Answer (score 9):

You can do it simply by setting the `backgroundColor` property of your textField. You can set it to either `white` or `transparent`

[image]

Here is an example

```
var txtSome = Ti.UI.createTextField({
   hintText : 'My hint text',
   width     : '75%',
   top   : '5%',
   backgroundColor : 'transparent'//or backgroundColor : 'white'
});
```

I know it's too late. But will help some one else.